# In Idiocracy, what is the food in the bucket supposed to be?

Tags: idiocracy

In Idiocracy, what is the food in the bucket supposed to be?

[image]

You see it later as well:
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bucket contains something called **Flaturin**, one of the major food groups on the FDAs revised food pyramid. The [film script](http://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/Idiocracy.pdf) simply describes it as ***"marshmallowy goop"*** without giving any further information about what it contains.

> Dizz is sitting in front of the TV in his La-Z-John, eating 
>   marshmallowy goop with his hands from a giant tub labeled - FOOD.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's meant to be grease.

Comment: Eugh, that's disgusting. Shovelling buckets of melted marshmallow by the handful into your face? This truly is the darkest timeline.

Comment: @SydneySleeper - Ah, but is it any grosser than popcorn with butter (AKA "*a way of eating two spoonfuls of butter without feeling bad about it"*)?

Comment: @Valorum Welp, looks like we're closer to this movie being reality than I thought

Comment: @SydneySleeper - I bought a bottle of water this morning and was very amused to read on the side that it has [added electrolytes](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Glac%C3%A9au%27s_smartwater_branded_bottled_water_has_added_electrolytes_added_for_taste-_2014-06-11_18-14.jpg/2448px-Glac%C3%A9au%27s_smartwater_branded_bottled_water_has_added_electrolytes_added_for_taste-_2014-06-11_18-14.jpg).

Comment: @Valorum a huge number of beverages have added electrolytes (i.e. salts).

Comment: @Valorum distilled water tastes bad (and can possibly do bad osmosis things to you) without them.

Comment: (when you try to upvote a comment and then realise it was yours)

Comment: Just to be clear, is the food pyramid printed on the side of the tub? This is sort of clever, implied that there is but one food supplier and they sell, besides a lot of Brawndo, literally junk food. This is disgusting but not way more disgusting than, say, Slim Jims.